# Tar Input/output error saving disk image to tape

Tags: backup, tar

I am saving data to tape with an LTO drive and have no problems with the majority of files. However, if I try to archive some disk image files (has occurred with iso & bin/cue) then I will get an error. For example:

```
$ tar -cvf /dev/st0 ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
tar: /dev/st0: Cannot write: Input/output error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

In this case the `ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso` file causes it to fail. If I run the same command but add in gzip compression `tar -czvf /dev/st0 [...]` it works just fine. Not all disk images have this problem though. The `ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso` file transfers just fine without gzip.

I'm guessing that there is some kind of `eof` data inside the disk image causing it to fail. I have tried adding the `-i` flag to ignore those though,

```
-i, --ignore-zeros
ignore zeroed blocks in archive (means EOF)
```

but it doesn't help. Could it be a drive level `eof` in the data? Is there a best practice data sanitation that I'm missing?

Though gzip would work, when doing large arbitrary backups I'd rather not have to gzip all files to be sure that I don't encounter this problem. This would remove any advantage the the LTO compression and shift the load to the CPU.

Comment: Anything else logged into `dmesg`, `kern.log`, `syslog` or anywhere else?

Comment: All three contain this message
[ 3829.256866] st 16:0:3:0: [st0] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 3829.256886] st 16:0:3:0: [st0] Add. Sense: Information unit iuCRC error detected

Comment: Actually it seems intermittent. I can run the command multiple times in a row and sometimes it works and other times it fails

Comment: CRC is a error detection technique. It's having issues validating the files it's writing. It could be an issue with data, or it could be an issue with the tape or drive. I hope this helps a bit, but I don't have a test tape drive to test.

Comment: Regarding data, maybe check if other people have had issues storing binary data and how they got around it.

Comment: I haven't found any other people with this sort of problem online. I can write the gzip'ed versions and other file types over and over again with no problems. So I don't think it is the tape or the drive.